# iPhone Can't deselect a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I have a RootViewController class which is inherited from UITableViewController.
When a cell is deselected by the user I want to enable/disable certain buttons on the toolbar.

How do I trap the deselect event?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(indexPath.row <= rowNumber)
    {
        [viewButtton setEnabled:NO];
        [editButtton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

I tried using this method but it doesn't seem to execute at all. Any ideas how cam this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a deselectRowAtIndexPath event, there is a method that you can call to deselect the indexPath, but looking at the SDK I do not see an event for this in the UITableViewDelegate: http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html.

Could you enable/disable certain buttons on the toolbar during the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: event?

-Rog

Answer (score 0):

This is in the current beta SDK only which means it could be buggy / changed / unsupported...

I did noticed that your method declaration doesn't match the SDK (at least, the version I have).

Try removing `animated:(BOOL)animated`; I don't think it's applicable here.

See line ~345 in `UITableView.h`, and/or right click on `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` and "Jump to Definition", where you'll probably find how the delegate method should be defined.

That said, if your goal is simply to "enable/disable certain buttons when a cell is selected",

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

should work just fine. This will occur after they select the cell and before it's deselected. 'deselect' has to do more with animation than user interaction. The only reason I can think you would want to use deselect is maybe the aesthetic value of ensuring your event only occurs after the select cell is no no longer highlighted.